# Tooltip ou Hint em rowEditor no Primefaces

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

Estou com um problema, queria adicionar um `tooltip` ou `hint` ao pousar o mouse sobre o ícone editar, confirmar e cancelar do `roweditor`e `celleditor` do `Primefaces`.

Já pesquisei e tentei usar css mas não deu muito certo.

```
.ui-icon .ui-icon-pencil:hover {
    content:"This is a hint";
    background:yellow;
    padding:.5em;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    opacity:.9;
}
```

Html do botão editar

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span>
```

Html do botão confirmar

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check"></span>
```

E do botão cancelar

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>
```

Tem como fazer?

Obrigado

Comment: Macario, poderia incluir o markup gerado pelo jsf (sem ser o facelets/jsp)? Em particular o  html do componente em que quer adicionar esse tooltip. Esta usando jQuery UI? O jQuery UI tem um componente de tooltip, baseado em javascript, não sei se atende ao seu requisito.

Comment: @Wakim este é código que o `Chrome` me mostra, claro que este componente esta dentro de uma `datatable`. Sobre o tooltip eu não sei se tem como usar neste caso por que de um 1 componente ele me gera três botões.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui tal fato como um milagre divino de sorte e inspiração para realizar tal fato.

Na sorte encontrei este seletor, no manual do Primefaces.

```
.ui-state-hover
```

Logo pensei, após pesquisar anteriormente, essa deve ser a propriedade quando passo o mouse sobre tal objeto e ele mostra o `hint`.

Então criei um método jQuery para toda vez que o elemento `div.ui-row-editor` é criado ele executa as atribuições.

```
$(document).on('mouseover click', 'div.ui-row-editor', function() {
    $('span.ui-icon-pencil').prop('title', 'Editar');
    $('span.ui-icon-close').prop('title', 'Cancelar');
    $('span.ui-icon-check').prop('title', 'Confirmar');
});
```

Bom ta aí para galera!

Vi algumas demandas em aberto no fórum do Primefaces mas consegui fazer, se houve alguma critica favor informar e quem sabe modificar!

Answer (score 1):

Macario, usei o pseudo-elemento `:after` para construir seu tooltip. É claro que ele pode ser estilizado, apenas fiz o mínimo para que ao passar o mouse em cima do elemento que precisa, ele apareça.

Além disso tinha um erro em seu seletor, esta usando a regra de filho `.ui-icon .ui-icon-pencil` em vez de `.ui-icon.ui-icon-pencil`, logo ele nunca aplicava a regra no elemento correto.

Ficou assim o CSS:

```
.ui-icon.ui-icon-pencil:hover:after,
.ui-icon.ui-icon-pencil:hover::after {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    /* Usei o atributo customizado data-tooltip para colocar uma mensagem no tooltip */
    background:yellow;
    padding:.5em;
    margin-left: 10px;
    opacity:.9;
}
```

Nesse caso o tooltip vai aparecer a direita do elemento. Se quiser que fique a esquerda, use o pseudo-elemento `:before`.

Usei duas notações: `:after` que foi definida no CSS2, e a notação `::after` do CSS3. As duas são iguais, porém a `::after` foi alterada para distinguir **pseudo-elements** de **pseudo-selectors**.

O HTML é o mesmo, porém acrescentei um atributo `data-tooltip` para customizar a mensagem do tooltip (isso pode ser gerado pelo seu componente, ao escrever o markup):

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" data-tooltip="Mensagem">Icon</span>
```

Criei um [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8awpj42/) para testar.

Mais infomações dê uma olhada na documentação dos pseudo-elementos: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after e https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before.

Comment: Cara talvez eu tenha entendido errado o que você me pediu, eu coloquei o código gerado pelo navegador pelo componente `<p:roweditor>`

Comment: Não é o `roweditor` que gera os `spans`/ícones que quer adicionar um tooltip?

Comment: Sim, vou deixar mais explicito, onde coloco a mensagem que quero que apareça na tela? Porque pelo que vi no seu exemplo na página o componente `span` já leva a o atributo que você deifiniu...

Comment: A mensagem eu coloquei no atributo `data-tooltip` que acredito que o `roweditor` não escreva. Para escrever eu recomendo extender esse componente e acrescentar o atributo. Se não for dessa forma, só com JavaScript.

Comment: Qual a forma mais simples? Porque acho que gerar um novo componente seria mais trabalhoso...Realmente ao rodar ele n herdou o atributo.

Comment: Na minha opinião seria extender o componente, basta olhar o código fonte do PrimeFaces e copiar o código do método que vai sobreescrever (adaptando para sua necessidade), já que não adianta muito reaproveitar o código da superclasse porque ele já vai ter fechado o markup. Por JavaScript também vai ter o problema da mensagem específica para cada tooltip, ai vai depender de qual componente de tooltip você vai usar para poder definir a mensagem.

Comment: Você tem algum post ou exemplo de como usar Js?

Comment: Se você ja está usando o jQuery UI, o primefaces usa, então recomendo esse componente: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/.